# JFrame not showing after isVisible() called, no errors

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, boxlayout

I am creating a simple Calculator for my CS class, I have finished all of the math and I'm trying to format my JFrame, I made a background panel, added a BoxLayout to it and then added my 3 other panels and then added the background panel to the JFrame, however after making the changes the JFrame never opens. Could someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```
public class Calculator implements ActionListener
{

    private JFrame myFrame;
    private JPanel buttonPanel;
    private JPanel resultPanel;
    private JPanel textPanel;
    public JPanel mainPanel;
    private JButton ADD;
    private JButton SUB;
    private JButton MULT;
    private JButton DIV;
    private JLabel resultLabel;
    private JTextField text1;
    private JTextField text2;

    public Calculator()
    {
        // Frame to contain panels
        int fx = 550;
        int fy = 300;
        myFrame = new JFrame("The Shittiest Calculator");
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myFrame.setSize(fx, fy);
        myFrame.setResizable(false);

        // Buttons to add to the buttonPanel
        ADD = new JButton("ADD");
        SUB = new JButton("SUBTRACT");
        MULT = new JButton("MULTIPLY");
        DIV = new JButton("DIVIDE");
        ADD.setName("addButton");
        SUB.setName("subButton");
        MULT.setName("multButton");
        DIV.setName("divButton");
        int x = 50;
        int y = 25;
        ADD.setSize(x, y);
        SUB.setSize(x, y);
        MULT.setSize(x, y);
        DIV.setSize(x, y);
        ADD.addActionListener(this);
        SUB.addActionListener(this);
        MULT.addActionListener(this);
        DIV.addActionListener(this);

        // Button Panel
        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(ADD);
        buttonPanel.add(SUB);
        buttonPanel.add(MULT);
        buttonPanel.add(DIV);

        // Result label
        resultLabel = new JLabel("Result = ");
        resultLabel.isVisible();

        // Result Panel
        resultPanel = new JPanel();
        resultPanel.isVisible();
        resultPanel.add(resultLabel);

        // Textfields
        text1 = new JTextField();
        text2 = new JTextField();
        text1.setName("leftOperand");
        text2.setName("rightOperand");
        text1.setColumns(10);
        text2.setColumns(10);

        // Textfield panel
        textPanel = new JPanel();
        textPanel.add(text1);
        textPanel.add(text2);

        //background Panel;
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        mainPanel.add(textPanel);
        mainPanel.add(resultPanel);
        mainPanel.add(buttonPanel);

        //Frame start
        myFrame.add(mainPanel);
        myFrame.isVisible();

    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return this.myFrame returns the frame.
     */
    public JFrame getFrame()
    {
        return this.myFrame;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param args main method 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Calculator calc = new Calculator();
    }
```

Comment: As well as `setVisible` (as mentioned in answers) you also need to call `pack`. Note that this is all covered in the standard tutorial at: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html

Comment: You need to fix a misconception: Just because you have no *compilation* errors, does not mean that your program "has no errors". The program isn't functioning correctly, and so by definition -- it *has* errors, *logical* errors, and these are the hardest to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Replace .isVisible() with .setVisible(true)

.isVisible() will return a boolean stating that it is visible or not at that moment, .setVisible() will actually set it to visible

Answer (score 0):

Replace .isVisible() with .setVisible(true)